# HTTP server and version within Python using socket library

Tags: python, http

```
import socket
```

I'm wondering how to get the web servers name and version for the Server response header for an HTTP server using the socket library:

Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)

Comment: Any decent HTTP library, including those that come with Python’s standard library, will let you do that. If you want examples, please elaborate on the problem you’re trying to solve.

Comment: It depends on which library are you using, but it's definitely possible. Please edit the question.

Comment: Sorry. I'm pretty new to Python. I didn't realize I have to get that information from the libraries I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to grab the [banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_grabbing) which is presented on the interesting ports of a server. For a lot of cases all you need is something like the following:

```
import sys
import socket

ip = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket()

s.connect((ip, port))
print s.recv(1024)
```

Since you mention Apache (httpd), I assume you would be interested in port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS, but honestly httpd could listen to any port. Since these are speaking HTTP(S) (a protocol which sits atop TCP) they will want a request to serve before responding to you, in this case you would need to send a valid HTTP request. The bare minimum is `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` so in that case you would need something like this:

```
import sys
import socket

ip = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])

s = socket.socket()

s.connect((ip, port))
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
print s.recv(1024)
```

Notice the `send` before the `recv`.

You would run that script like so:

```
$ python grab_banner.py <IP_ADDRESS> <PORT>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 03:12:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Fedora)
Last-Modified: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 03:06:19 GMT
ETag: "17-522d1031eac3e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 23
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
```

All of that being said if this **isn't** just an exercise in Python and socket programming you may wish to check out nmap as it does a wonderful job of everything you seem to be doing, it's  fast and has many options (some are pretty advanced, but google can help here).

```
$ sudo yum install nmap
...
$ nmap -sV google.com

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-23 22:45 EDT
Nmap scan report for google.com (204.186.215.24)
Host is up (0.013s latency).
Other addresses for google.com (not scanned): 204.186.215.38 204.186.215.39 204.186.215.46 204.186.215.45 204.186.215.32 204.186.215.59 204.186.215.31 204.186.215.18 204.186.215.25 204.186.215.53 204.186.215.52
rDNS record for 204.186.215.24: cache.google.com
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE  VERSION
80/tcp  open  http     Google httpd 2.0 (GFE)
443/tcp open  ssl/http Google httpd 2.0 (GFE)
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 23.02 seconds
```

Note the `-sV` enables server and version checking. Also note that you may not want to hit google with this too many times as they might get very curious.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I should have specified that I'm writing a web server and needed the web server version to build a string for the Server response header. I found this code that worked.                                        import subprocess                                                                                                     web_version = subprocess.check_output(["apache2", "-v"])
web_line = web_version.split('\n')[0]
web_info = web_line.split(':')[1]
web_server_header = "Server:" + web_info + "\n"

Comment: You should know that the output of the executable is not what it sends to clients. For that see the second and third block of code in my answer.